# Why using Autoencoder in nlp seem hard to do?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language, autoencoders

I want to implement an autoencoder with theano to express each article. When I made it following the tutorial of UFLDL. I found that it's hard to get gradient descent(I use LBFGS). I want to know whether it is due to the sparsity of the BOW input?

Answer (score 2):

Typically people train autoencoders on the sentence level and not for entire articles. That may be why you are having trouble training your model.